# Expand C/C++ function macros without preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

How would I test/expand all the function macros, in a C/C++ file, without running it through a preprocessor?
For example, is there a program or method which would change this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define AAA(a) cout << "function "  << a << endl
using namespace std;
int main(){
AAA(12);
}
```

into this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
cout << "function " << 12 << endl;
}
```

I don't want to run through preprocessor because all the includes in the files make the "gcc -E <>" output really ugly, I just want a couple simple macro expansions without all the overhead.

Comment: You could probably write some code that uses clang as a library, and use it's preprocessor. Unless `grep -v ^\#include myfile|gcc -E` is good enough for you.

Comment: Resharper for C++ lets you do this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mats, I'll look into Clang. However, it will be iterating over 33k+ lines of code, so I think the grep would turn out a little dirty. I'm on a mac right now but I'll hop on a VM and give Resharper a shot too.

Comment: Why would number of lines matter to grep? Surely you only care about #includes to keep the code clean?

Comment: That would output the preprocessed code, however that code wouldn't have the include statements. So then when I need to actually compile the program I would have expanded the macros but it wouldn't compile because all the missing dependencies. I would have to programmatically remove all the #includes, store them. Preprocess the file, then insert them back in. If worse comes to worse thats what I'll end up doing.

Comment: @Involution: It would be easier to just prefix the `#include` with `// {unique tag}`, run that through an ordinary preprocessor, and then remove `// {unique tag}` again.

Comment: Thought that worked @MSalters However the preprocessor removes the #include tags entirely when commented out. Dependencies also removed. Same problem as above, the include statements disappear when commented out. Real headscratcher.

Comment: @Involution: GCC keeps comments with the `-C` option.

Comment: @MSalters Of course, all of this relies on macro definitions not being taken from `#include`d files.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Your included headers could include macros that you want to expand in the body, for example. Or did you mean to not expand any macros that come from headers? The preprocessor has absolutely no way of distinguishing what you want from what you don't want in this case.

If you know in advance this is not the case, then I recommend simply writing a script to remove the includes and then run that through the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

I heard all possible negative answers on the topic:

- macros can only be expanded not evaluated
- processor should parse also include files
- nested macros can be over-complicated
- conditional preprocessing can be tricky
- macros are evil just avoid them
- etc
  etc....

They are all true, but IMO they collide with the reality of everydays programming.

In fact, working on old C project where macros were mostly simply used as functions this became of crucial importance for me. Generating all preprocessed files with /P works but is overkilling and time taking. I just needed a tool that expands a simple macro defined a few lines above or at maximum in other file.

How to do that?

1 Onl,inux simply use GDB and his expand macros capabilities 
2 On windows I use https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/ integrated into Visual Studio

So, Yes, in a practical sense, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Protect the `#include`s from getting expanded, run the preprocessor textually, remove the `# 1 "<stdint>"` etc. junk the textual preprocessor generates and reexpose the protected `#include`s.

This shell command does it:

```
sed 's|^\([ \t]*#[ \t]*include\)|magic_fjdsa9f8j932j9\1|' | cpp | \
     sed 's|^magic_fjdsa9f8j932j9||; /^# [0-9]/d'
```

as long as you keep the include word together instead of doing crazy shit like

```
#i\
ncl\
u??/
de <iostream>
```

(above you can see 2 backslash continuation lines + 1 trigraph (??/ == \ ) backslash continuation line).

If you wish, you can protect `#if`s `#ifdef`s `#ifndef`s `#endif`s and `#else`s the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you want to see file.c. If it contains the function main, you would need to change the name of that function for this to work. The following prints the file to stdout, only with moderate added ugliness.

```
#include "file.c"
#include <stdio.h>

#define X(...) #__VA_ARGS__

void print_file( char* s )
{
   // a loop here to move through s until some identifier is found
   // in the original file, say a comment that says: //___START___HERE___
   while(*s){
      if( *s=='{' | *s=='}' | *s=='#' ) printf("\n");
      printf("%c",*s);
      if( *s==';' ) printf("\n");
      }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    print_file(X(
    #include "file.c"
    ));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will print all includes in the file.

Comment: @Puppy, that is a really minor issue. You simply don't print until you find the name main changed into, or some set comment, or something. Thats like 2 lines of extra code.

Comment: I'm not saying to parse it, just put a comment in the origional file where you want to start printing. Increment s until !strcmp(s,c), where c is the comment. The preprocessing is all done by including the original file, and so including all its macros.

Comment: You're assuming that no code in the includes happens to match the new name/special comment.

Comment: That should be pretty easy to get right. If your really worried, use an md5sum. You are more likely to get hit by a meteor before finishing that to have a conflict that way. Its not like OP needs to deploy this as some sort of commercial solution, it just needs to work when its used. And if it doesn't, it can just be tweaked.

Comment: Obviously, it would be nice to have a clean solution. But a dirty solution is better than "won't work".