# Determine the expansion of a C macro

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Is there a way to determine the "final value" of a expanded C macro by inspecting the compiled object or by running some form of gcc -E on the .c or .h file?

test.h

```
#define AAA 1
#define BBB 10
#define CCC (AAA+BBB)
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(){
   printf("%d\n", CCC);
   return 0;
}
```

Thus is there someway to get the expanded value either:

```
#define CCC 11
```

or

```
#define CCC (1+10)
```

If compiled with

```
gcc -dM -E test.c | grep CCC
```

or

```
gcc -dD -E test.c | grep CCC
```

outputs

```
#define CCC (AAA+BBB)
```

which requires me to still know what `AAA` and `BBB` are.

Compiled with:

```
gcc -E test.c
```

Gives (skipping the boilerplate):

```
# 4 "test.c"
int main(){
printf("%d\n", (1+10));
return 0;
}
```

While its expanded `CCC` I've now lost the mapping back to `CCC`.

Edit:
As it was unclear, what i'd like is someway to determine what CCC is (either 11 or 1+10 (as the gcc -E example showed it only inserted (1+10) not 11), preferably without altering the code itself. Printf was a bad idea to use in the MRE, what i actually had in mind was code like:

```
struct my_struct {
    int my_array[CCC]
    ... other stuff ...
}
```

The question is how big is my_array, so i can make a struct in another language (python via ctypes) and know how much space i need. I know for structs i can use pahole but was hoping to do this with only gcc and in the more general case (say a global array not in a struct).

Comment: I have read the question twice. Could not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Isn't (1+10) the final value? What output do you want?

Comment: Is something like `printf("'%s" %d\n", #CCC, CCC);` OK to report the macro name and expansion?

Comment: Macro processing is an all-or-nothing deal.

Comment: Code could use `_Static_assert()` to test the value at compile time to perhaps meet a higher level compliance objective `_Static_assert(CCC > 0 && CCC < 20, "CCC out of expected range");
`

Comment: So you want to see an incomplete expansion? It can be done using special tools. Eclipse CDT has a step-by-step expansion tool.

Comment: Can somebody name the duplicate? I know that there is one but admit that I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932534/expand-c-c-function-macros-without-preprocessor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At no point will the preprocessor ever create

```
#define CCC (1+10)
```

The expansion of `CCC` is always `(AAA+BBB)`; it's just that the result of macro expansion is rescanned for more macros to expand, at which point `AAA` and `BBB` turn into `1` and `10`, respectively.

Perhaps a clearer example of this is

```
#define AAA 1
#define CCC AAA
#define AAA "hello"

size_t x = sizeof CCC;
```

This code will expand to `"hello"`, not `1`. `CCC` always has a value of `AAA`; it's just that by the time `size_t x = sizeof CCC;` is processed, `AAA` itself will turn into `"hello"`.

This example also demonstrates that macros can be redefined, so there may not even be a single answer to "what is the value of `CCC`?".

That's why there's no simple compiler invocation or switch; what you want simply doesn't exist.

That said, if you can use custom code, you can just run e.g.

```
#define AAA 1
#define BBB 10
#define CCC (AAA+BBB)
CCC
```

through `gcc -P -E` and the result will be just `(1+10)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define AAA 1
#define BBB 2
#define CCC (AAA+BBB)

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define PASTE(x) STRINGIFY(x)


int main(void)
{
  printf("CCC = '%s'\n", PASTE(CCC));
}
```

prints

```
CCC = '(1+10)'
```

An alternative version printing the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define AAA 1
#define BBB 2
#define CCC (AAA+BBB)

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define INTERMEDIATE(x) #x " = '" STRINGIFY(x) "'"

int main(void)
{
  printf("%s\n", INTERMEDIATE(CCC));
}
```